# Trying to a Select Count where it needs to count the difference between a certain date and current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff, ssms-2014

It's not quite working for me!

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as [generic] 
FROM [Log]
Where value IN (Select ID, tsSendDocument, sysReceivedFrom
WHERE sysReceivedFrom = 'generic' AND 
DATEDIFF(hour, tsSendDocument, GetDate()) > 2)
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

I want it to to count every time the tsSendDocument column is older than 2 hours. It will eventually give me a count that's equal to 1. I have a table set up to alert me if the value = 1, which means that the tsSendDocument is older than 2 hours.

Do this make any sense?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You mention something in the comments about only wanting the most recent. Not sure what you mean there. We need sample data and desired output along with a complete explanation of the business rules.

Comment: Okay so. I have a small business where I receive documents, convert them to a certain format and send them to the receiver. I want to make sure, that there is a constant flow of sent documents, thus make sure that there is always a sent document younger than two hours. If the last document I sent is older than two hours, it might mean that there's something wrong with my service. I then want to do a select count query. If the last document is older than hours, the count result will equal 1. If it's younger, it's 0. That's why I only want it to count the last table entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, I've understood that you want to check if the last entry is older than 2 hours, so this should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN tsSendDocument < DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [generic]
FROM [Log]
ORDER BY tsSendDocument DESC
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Sorry for the vague description, I'm slowly learning SQL at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want only aggregation :

```
Select COUNT(*) 
FROM Log
WHERE sysReceivedFrom = 'generic' AND 
      DATEDIFF(hour, tsSendDocument, GetDate()) > = 2;
```

`subquery` will only return one expression when you specified `IN` or`NOT IN` clause.

Comment: But the problem with that is that I only want it to count on the newest entry. Else, it will currently count on the whole table which will contain a lot of entries older than two hours. It has to be exclusively the newest entry so that the Count result will be 1 if the newest entry is older than 2 hours.

Comment: This looks pretty good but be careful using DATEDIFF here. It looks only at the date thresholds being crossed. So this could return rows that are just over one hour apart. This is also not SARGable. Might be more accurate to use "Where tsSendDocument < dateadd(hour, -2, getdate())". This would be more accurate and SARGable. :)

Comment: Thank you, Sean. How do I limit it to the top row then? Got an idea?